# VSCode terminal is just white text?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

what I want

[image: what I want]

what I have

[image: what I have]

used terminal: powershell

[image: powershell]

The text I have in the VS Code terminal only appears in white, and I'd like the text to be in different colors like yellow.

Edit: I'm using powershell

Comment: what is that first screenshot of? where did you take it from? what shell are you using?

Comment: I'm using powershell

Comment: It is the `PSReadLine` module that provides the syntax coloring. It is normally automatically loaded in interactive PowerShell sessions. You can try `Import-Module PSReadLine -Verbose` to see what happens if you load it on demand.

Comment: give me this error: "Import-Module : The specified module 'PSReadLine' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory." and when I try to use this command (Install-Module -Name PSReadLine -Force -SkipPublisherCheck) give me this error: Install-Module : The term 'Install-Module' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: Looks like your PowerShell installation is corrupted. In the simplest case, the problem is caused only by `$env:PSModulePath`. Run the following (all on a single line), then try the `Import-Module` / `Install-Module` commands again: `$env:PSModulePath = "$HOME\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;$env:ProgramFiles\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;$env:WinDir\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules"`

Comment: I had tried everything and it finally worked :O

Comment: However, when I close VSCode and open it again, the letters go back to being white :/

Comment: That is to be expected - the command I suggested takes effect for the _current_ session only. The question is: What changes the value of `$env:PSModulePath` in your system on startup? What is its initial value in Visual Studio Code? (By default, a machine-level persistent definition should exists; however, even without it PowerShell should define the relevant entries _automatically_; however, if the process that launched PowerShell has an explicit definition, that definition is used.)

Comment: what commands should I use to answer those questions?

Comment: Just submit `$env:PSModulePath` in the integrated terminal - it prints the current process-level value. `[environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PSModulePath', 'Machine')` tells you the persistent machine-level definition (which should be the equivalent of `"$env:ProgramFiles\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;$env:WinDir\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules;"`. `[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PSModulePath', 'User')` tells you the user-level one (normally, there isn't one).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are on Windows.

tldr **Command Prompt doesn't have color, you want to use Powershell (or equivalent)**

Since you are Windows, the reason the "git" isn't colored yellow is because you are most likely using Command Prompt as the Shell launched in VSCode.

Command Prompt to the best of my knowledge does not have coloring support in the default shell interface (if you launch command prompt by itself, there are no colors).

However, Powershell does have coloring. So the first picture is most likely using Powershell or some other shell that supports coloring.

**Switching shells**

In order to Switch between different shells, you need to launch Powershell instead of Command prompt by clicking the dropdown next to the "+" next to the Terminal panel:

[image: And make sure it says powershell]

Then you want to select Powershell. Then you should have an instance of the terminal where it will be able to launch with colored text.

Comment: I'm using powershell